# Trying to troubleshoot program for extracting author names for articles in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a program that takes a csv of New York Times article links and then outputs a csv of respective author names.
I'm using bs4 and my code should work since I'm searching for the right tag and class that contains an author's name for every New York Times article.

For reference, the author name always seems to be contained within a  tag with class `css-1baulvz last-byline` for any New York Times article, regardless of whether or not the article has a paywall on it.

However, when I run the code, my output csv keeps returning `Author not found` for nearly every single article (like 3 out of 100 of the articles return an author name). I'm wondering if anybody could help me and take a look at my code for my `extract_author` function?

```
def extract_author(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # List of possible tags where the author's name can be found
    author_tags = [
        {'tag': 'span', 'class': 'css-1baulvz last-byline'},
        {'tag': 'a', 'class': 'css-n8ff4n e1jsehar0'}
    ]
    
    for author_tag in author_tags:
        author = soup.find(author_tag['tag'], {'class': author_tag['class']})
        if author:
            return author.text.strip()
    
    return 'Author not found'
```

Comment: The classes you're using are of a format that suggests a highly dynamic web page. You probably need to use *selenium* (or equivalent). You almost certainly will not be able to rely on constant class identifiers. Give some examples of the URLs you're using

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here are some sample urls I am using: https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/20/opinion/gay-trans-lgbt-americans.html        https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/21/podcasts/transcript-ezra-klein-interviews-barbara-kingsolver.html               They all seem to contain the same class "css-1baulvz last-byline" on a span tag that contains the author's name so I'm having a hard time figuring out why the names aren't being pulled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the author name from a meta tag. If you have many URLs (in a list or some other iterable) then you can do this efficiently with some judicious multithreading.

For example:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from bs4.element import Tag
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from sys import stderr

URLS = [
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/20/opinion/gay-trans-lgbt-americans.html',
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/28/opinion/travel-vacation.html',
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/28/opinion/ron-desantis-trump-campaign.html',
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/28/opinion/fentanyl-mandatory-drug-sentences.html',
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/28/opinion/new-york-city-metro-ravitch.html',
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/30/opinion/state-of-evangelical-america.html',
    'https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/30/opinion/international-world/oppenheimer-nuclear-bomb-cancer.html'
]
HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 13_4_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.5 Safari/605.1.15'
    }
ATTRS = {
    'name': 'byl'
}

def extract_author(url: str) -> str:
    try:
        with get(url, headers=HEADERS) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            soup = BS(response.text, 'lxml')
            if (meta := soup.find('meta', attrs=ATTRS)):
                if isinstance(meta, Tag):
                    if (content := meta.get('content')) and isinstance(content, str):
                        fw, *r = content.split()
                        return ' '.join(r) if fw == 'By' else content
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, file=stderr)
    return 'Name not found'

with ThreadPool() as pool:
    print(*pool.map_async(extract_author, URLS).get(), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Jane Coaston
Ross Douthat
David Firestone
Maia Szalavitz
Nicole Gelinas
Tish Harrison Warren
Tina Cordova
```